# ImportError: No module named lxml.etree ( windows )

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After creating a binary with pyInstaller and executing it,  i receive the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named lxml.etree
```

i have downloaded and installd the lxml binary ( lxml-3.0.1.win32-py2.7.‌exe )   from [lfd.uce.edu](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Python 2.7 , but i still have the error .

This error only occurs with the binary. if i execute the .py file it runs well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The version im using is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it and it workes fine.
Is it possible that you accidentally installed the lxml in the wrong python interpreter directory? Do you have several python interpreters installed?

Comment: No, just one version installed. :|